How to remove Minecraft from Ubuntu 22.04?
I bought the Debian version of Minecraft and installed it using the .deb file, but now I can't figure out for the life of me how to remove it. Every terminal commmand I've found does not work. Most seem to assume you installed it through snap. I did not; I downloaded the Minecraft.deb file from Minecraft's website.
I've also been wary of the fact that it doesn't fully work if you're not online when you start it up. Oddly, it only does its loading screen thing if you're online. Yeah, it'll start up, and you can load your games, though you can't use a custom skin.
I've tried looking in installed programs, but oddly it's not listed in there. Right-clicking on the launcher and telling it to Show me details instead shows me details for a program called creeperx. Literally doing a search for it just gives me download links. I did find the folder it's installed in, but deleting it doesn't stop the launcher icon from working.
What do I have to do to get rid of this?

I created a bug report about the software-installation tag automatically becoming software-uninstall https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20549/bug-software-uninstall-tag-automatically-becomes-software-installation

Open a terminal, and enter the following command
sudo apt remove minecraft-launcher

You will be prompted for your password. The computer will not show any characters when you type your password for security reasons, but it can read the characters you type. Just type the password and press enter.

Well, that did work. Nothing other than the install file and the folder I was keeping my skins in are now present. Hopefully I won't have any problems with it now...

On a side note, will that command work with any installed program? i've seen it several times now. I don't even understand what its doing honestly, other than that the 'sudo' command lets you do things as an 'administrator'. I only know that because of news that microsoft decided to add that to windows 11 or something.

sudo gives you admin rights to change system files. apt is the package manager, which removes the program, here minecraft-launcher. If you know the name of the program installed as deb/apt, you can use the command sudo apt remove program to remove it. Be aware that removing system packages will break your installation. For programs installed with snap (e.g. from the app store), you will have to do sudo snap remove program

I've been told its bad to install things through snap. I installed steam through snap, and it was giving me all manner of weird issues until I removed it and installed it through a proper download. I don't have anything installed through snap, minus maybe what came with the system.
